# how to generate dynamic urls to prevent direct downloads?

Tags: php

I want to generate a download url for my website current is like [this](http://www.website.com/something.rar) but it is directly accessible i dont want people to copy paste link and then direct start download and i am sending download link through email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent direct access/download to mp3/wav files while allowing a flash player to access them with .htaccess (or PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408927/how-do-i-prevent-direct-access-download-to-mp3-wav-files-while-allowing-a-flash)

Comment: You can also do this by starting the session. If session dont exist dont set the header to download file location. else set the header to download file. Even you can also set the time for which the ip/user is allowed to download that file :)

Answer (score 3):

1: Don't give the users Direct link to files. Put these files a separate folder protected by .htaccess. For example: Put all the files to a directory named "User_Files" and under that make this .htaccess file:

```
deny from all
```

So the users can not directly access this file.

2: Create a php script that reads the file to the user. You can put session or login checks before reading the file like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) AND $_SESSION['logged_in'] == 1){ //change it to suit your needs to verify whatever you want before reading file to user
    $file = "Files/something.rar";
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
}
```

So when the user visits http://yourdomain.com/your_script.php the PHP will read the file to user.

Comment: i have no login module and want to serve link of the file using email

Answer (score 3):

You can create a script telling PHP to serve the file. Here is a great function I got sometime ago somewhere from SO:

**download.php**

```
function send_download($file){
    $basename = basename($file);
    $length   = sprintf("%u", filesize($file));

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $basename . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $length);

    set_time_limit(0);
    ob_get_clean(); 
    readfile($file);
    ob_end_flush(); 
}

$file="file/download/path";
send_download($file);
```

So your download link would look like:

```
something.com/download.php?id=some_hash_or_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php

  //start session
  session_start();

  function randomkey( $length ) {
      $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
      return substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length);
  }

  //if the session exist
  if(isset($_SESSION['sessionid'])){

        //check session id 
    if($_SESSION['sessionid'] == $_GET['sessionid']){
        echo 'Download script here! for file :' . $_GET['fileid'];
        session_destroy(); //to avoid reapply for download

      }else{ //if user has provided false sessions.
        echo 'Redirect user to the page again!'; 
        session_destroy(); //to avoid reapply for download
      }

  }else{

      //if session not exist

  //create a temporary session
  $sessionid = randomkey(20);
  $_SESSION['sessionid'] = $sessionid;

  ?>
  <form action="" method="get">
      <input type="hidden" name="sessionid" value="<?php echo $sessionid ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="fileid" value="File you want the user to download">
      <input type="submit" value="download">
  </form>

  <?php

  }

  ?>
```