# How to play an mp3 on a webpage but disallow that sound to be downloaded?

Tags: html, audio, download, mp3

I have a client in the music industry who has a new album out. Upon loading the given page of the album record company, I was somewhat surprised to find that it was trivially easy to download the sound from their website, the sound runs in the following source code, in HTML5:

```
<div class="sqs-audio-embed" data-url="https://...fileserverURL...SD+Master+V2.mp3" data-mime-type="" data-title="title" data-author="author" data-show-download="false" data-design-style="legacy" data-duration-in-ms="761000" data-color-theme="light" id="yui_3_17_2_1_144058079_1116">
    <div id="yui_3_17_2_1_149458079_1120" class="yui3-widget sqs-widget sqs-audio-player play-state-stopped ready-state-initialized">
     <div id="yui_3_17_2_1_149058079_1122" class="sqs-audio-player-content">
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

It's an enbedded URL, based on another domain.

So my question is....

## How can a sound be played on a website but deny a direct download or a direct link?

**My thoughts:**

**1)** I imagine, using something like a custom **Content Security Policy** on the *fileserverURL* could do the trick, denying direct access unless the access comes from unless it's the domain name of the record company website (*for example*).

**2)** Could an `.htaccess` request -such as those that block image direct access- also work, with some sort of exception if being played/called via a certain domain or webpage?

---

**Summary:**

- Mp3 file.
- File is on a different URL domain than the website
- File can be played on the website but direct links should not be allowed
- Unless there's no other way, Javascript would like to be avoided

> I have looked at other questions on Stack Overflow but I didn't find any (*any!*) that related to practical workarounds for the above situation (allow play disallow direct access). The closest I found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408927/how-do-i-prevent-direct-access-download-to-mp3-wav-files-while-allowing-a-flash) from 2010 which seems to imply the above can't be done, but I am sure it can (now) be done if the two servers (*filehost* and *website*) are set to allow acces to a file *if only* via the website server acting as a gatekeeper, as in **point 1**, above.)

---

> Yes, I'm also aware that committed people can copy the sound from the downloaded browser cache (from which the sound is actually played), but I'm not getting *too* obsessive over this, just, well, a little....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSP isn't designed for this, it's for the opposite problem: the operator on the site wants to prevent loading content from a different server (you're the operator of the different server and you want to keep most sites from loading your content).

Your second idea should work to solve the problem, as you've outlined. Deep-linking prevention doesn't care if it's an MP3 or a JPEG. It would have to be on the site that's hosting the mp3. Pulling it from the browser or faking the origin are both still trivial.

As painful as it is for me to say this, you should probably be looking [Encrypted Media Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_Media_Extensions), for a far more complete (if harder to implement) solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was looking at using CSP to only allow a certain responder and no other, but the more I think about it, maybe CSP doesn't work on direct-link access. EME looks like an encryption API rather than a complete tool, but both answers here so far note it, so it's definitely worth me looking into more. Cheers.

Comment: Well, it deals with encryption and key distribution. Like all DRM, the idea is that you encrypt the data, then hand the user's player a key to read it. The spec requires everyone implement "Clearkey" but that's not considered suitable for production use.

You would probably want a combination of widevine (www.widevine.com), playready (https://www.microsoft.com/playready/), and/or fairplay (https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/) systems

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest looking at EME (encrypted media extensions).

here is a tutorial on it https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/

Comment: Thanks, a cursory look at EME it (looks like javascript) looks like only half the process, it's a standard API, rather than a complete solution. Could you provide an example of its usage on a HTML5 page?

Comment: looks like there also are implementation examples in the tutorial, it still uses html5's video/audio playback.

Comment: hah,yeah I have only just reached that point on the page..... (*still it's good practise to put an example in an SO answer incase the linked page ever disappears in the future*)